# VALUE! Ignore text in excel cell calculation

Tags: excel-2010

I often run into `VALUE!` errors in my calculations because they contain numbers and text. How can I leave the text in the cell and proceed with the calculation?

For example:

cell `A1` contents look like this: `101.1 J`

cell `A2` contents look like this: `500 U`

cell `A3` contents look like this: `0.2`

If I want to add `A1`+`A2`+`A3` into cell `A4`, how can I ignore the `J` and `U` to calculate `101.1`+`500`+`0.2` to get `602.3` in cell `A4`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason either of the answers below did not help you?

Answer (score 4):

You need extract the values from the strings - and this can only be done if you have some kind of information about the format to the numbers. In your example, you could place the following formula in B1:B3 and then add a `=SUM(B1:B3)`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)))
```

The above formula will extract the number and convert it to a value - unless it was already a number.

Answer (score 3):

**Using Custom Function**

Place below code in Standard Module

```
Function add_num(cell1, ParamArray Arr() As Variant)

    Dim temp As Double
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        temp = temp + GetNumber(Arr(i))
    Next

    add_num = GetNumber(cell1.Value) + temp
End Function

Function GetNumber(ByVal str As String) As Double
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.Global = True

    objRegEx.Pattern = "\d{1,2}([\.,][\d{1,2}])?"

    Set allMatches = objRegEx.Execute(str)

    For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1
        result = result & allMatches.Item(i)
    Next

    GetNumber = result
End Function
```

`add_num function` can be called from excel interface using `=addnum(<cells>)`. It accepts multiple cells.

[image]